# Can I use an external url for creating an Android app with CrossWalk?

Tags: crosswalk-runtime

I have a published web application and I would like to build an android application that will open it. I am trying to use Crosswalk for that but I don't find any information of how to set the manifest.json with the external url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given an answer by their Twitter:

> Crosswalk Project ‏@xwalk_project  2h2 hours ago @ronenfe yes, use
>   make_apk --app-url=APP_URL

Answer (score 1):

Create a manifest.json file for your application and set the "start_url" field to the external URL you wish to use.

This works both with the (now deprecated) make_apk and the newer crosswalk-app-tools.